# How to resolve Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (no such file to load -- java)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this problem. I'm getting the error:

```
rake db:migrate
(in /home/EXPRESS.LOCAL/shevchenko/web/tmp)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/paperclip/tasks and vendor/plugins/restful-authentication/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/EXPRESS.LOCAL/shevchenko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (no such file to load -- java)
```

I'm trying uninstall rake 0.9.2.2 and install 0.8.7, then change adapter:mysql to adapter:mysql2.

Here is my gem:

```
bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (2.3.8)
  * actionpack (2.3.8)
  * activerecord (2.3.8)
  * activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.2.1)
  * activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.2.2.1)
  * activeresource (2.3.8)
  * activesupport (2.3.8)
  * bundler (1.2.1)
  * jdbc-mysql (5.1.13)
  * mysql2 (0.3.6)
  * rack (1.1.3)
  * rails (2.3.8)
  * rake (0.8.7)
```

Here is the gem env output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.4.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/EXPRESS.LOCAL/shevchenko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/EXPRESS.LOCAL/shevchenko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/EXPRESS.LOCAL/shevchenko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/EXPRESS.LOCAL/shevchenko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371
     - /home/EXPRESS.LOCAL/shevchenko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this because version of gem `mysql2`, edit your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "mysql2", "0.2.6"
```

And run bundle install and run migrate again.

Comment: thnx 4 answer, i did't, but take next error: rake db:migrate
(in /home/EXPRESS.LOCAL/shevchenko/web/tmp)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/paperclip/tasks and vendor/plugins/restful-authentication/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/EXPRESS.LOCAL/shevchenko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
rake aborted!
undefined method `ping' for #<Mysql2::Client:0xb62650dc>

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: @cybern0va but your database has migrated or not?

Comment: no. But i update mysql2 to the latest version and my database migrate, but i'm getting error: WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.11) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
PS sorry 4 my english :)

Comment: so, is it worked? it seems you only can use versions `0.2.x` because your rails version is 2.3.8.